# Buffer size audio stream xamarin form

Tags: c#, android

I create test android app in c#. This app stream audio the web. This method:
[C# android stream online radio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343161/xamarin-android-c-sharp-play-audio-stream-online-radio).

I qestion:  How to set buffer size the player? The player start mobilphone about 30 second. The visual studio emulator start 5 seconds about (computer internet speed bigger than phone wifi).
Thanks Gabee.

Comment: The delay is most likely due to the connection not completing (not the buffer size).  Often a 30 second wait is due to the code waiting for a proxy and then working after the proxy completes.  Try setting proxy to null : myWebRequest.Proxy=null;  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest.proxy?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Hello! How to bypass proxy the app settings?

Comment: I said "myWebRequest.Proxy=null;"

Comment: Ok Thank you! :) I question how to this method?
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
player.SetAudioStreamType (Stream.Music);
player.SetDataSource ("http://media.vmariel.ru:8000/puls");
player.Prepare();
player.Start();

Comment: The Media Play can directly play music fro a URL.  Your android may not have a MediaPlayer.  You also may want to download music without playing.